# AWS lambda triggers on s3 object push but file is not present

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have a AWS lambda function which invokes whenever there is a object push happens in s3 bucket and I've also added functionality which sends notification mail if there is any error in lambda function.

For some data it works fine, meaning whenever there is a PUT operation happens in s3, lambda function will take data and process it properly.
But, I'm getting a error from lambda which says
"error: The specified S3 prefix '<file_path>' does not exist"
and when I checked the s3 path, the file does not exists there.

Also there is no expiration time for the objects.

So, anyone has any idea why the lambda function is triggering when there is no file on the particular path ?

Comment: How the file is push/put to the s3 bucket? S3 trigger is configured for what type of operations on s3 bucket?

Comment: Can you share the relevant lambda code too?

Comment: s3 trigger is configured for PUT object operation. There is one API which puts the object in s3 and once the object is in s3, lambda triggers.

Comment: This should not be possible. There is likely an explanation for it, such as the Lambda function not retrieving the correct Key, or the object being deleted by another process. You should add debug code to see the Bucket & Key that is being passed to the function, and then investigate whether the object is present.

Comment: Can to share the relevant lambda code too?

Comment: Couple of things you could do, is look for naming pattern on the file that you are interested if possible and trigger lambda based on name.

Look at any other processes that might be writing/deleting files from the s3 bucket, which might be causing this scenario. 

Curious to know if you are able to replicate this. 

Also, hopefully, versioning is turned on, so that you know you can go and look into the history of the files in s3.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using '/tmp/..' in your s3 prefix?

eg.

```
path = f"/tmp/myobject.json"
```

Comment: No, nothing like '/tmp/'.